# CSS Selector for Nested List

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to select only the li's from the first list not the nested list.  I thought that ul > li would accomplish this but it is instead selecting all of the li's.  i tried ul li as well and this still selected all of the list items.  So my question is how do I select only the first level list items? Also why is this not working? My understanding of the > operator was that it selects only direct children of the preceding element?  Is this understanding wrong?

```css
ul>li {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Comments</span>
    <ol>
      <li>Comment #1</li>
      <li>Comment #2</li>
      <li>Comment #3</li>
      <li>Comment #4</li>
      <li>Comment #5</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Attachments</span>
    <ol>
      <li>Attachment #1</li>
      <li>Attachment #2</li>
      <li>Attachment #3</li>
      <li>Attachment #4</li>
      <li>Attachment #5</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Accounting Strings</span>
    <ol>
      <li>Accounting String #1</li>
      <li>Accounting String #2</li>
      <li>Accounting String #3</li>
      <li>Accounting String #4</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Properties</span>
    <ol>
      <li>Property #1</li>
      <li>Property #2</li>
      <li>Property #3</li>
      <li>Property #4</li>
      <li>Property #5</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is selecting all the li elements within that ul. What do you want not to have background red?

Answer (score 1):

In your case [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) should work:

```css
ul>li:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Comments</span>
    <ol>
      <li>Comment #1</li>
      <li>Comment #2</li>
      <li>Comment #3</li>
      <li>Comment #4</li>
      <li>Comment #5</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Attachments</span>
    <ol>
      <li>Attachment #1</li>
      <li>Attachment #2</li>
      <li>Attachment #3</li>
      <li>Attachment #4</li>
      <li>Attachment #5</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Accounting Strings</span>
    <ol>
      <li>Accounting String #1</li>
      <li>Accounting String #2</li>
      <li>Accounting String #3</li>
      <li>Accounting String #4</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Properties</span>
    <ol>
      <li>Property #1</li>
      <li>Property #2</li>
      <li>Property #3</li>
      <li>Property #4</li>
      <li>Property #5</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that if you don't want the span with "Comments" highlighted, change the selector to
`ul > li:first-of-type > ol`

Comment: You may want to add your answer to the original question, rather than this duplicate.